# File deletion in c++

Tags: c++, file, delete-file

I want to delete a file whose path is stored in a `std::string` object.
I know `remove()` in `<cstdio>`, but it takes a `const char *` as argument.
So is there any direct method to delete the file, like a function which takes the string object as its input?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about:

```
string fileName;
//...
remove(fileName.c_str());
```

Of course, you can always define

```
int remove(std::string const& fileName)
{
    return remove(fileName.c_str());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `std::string` object will supply you with a `const char*` representation via the `c_str()` method:

```
std::string filename = ...
remove(filename.c_str());
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::string` has a method called `c_str()` that will return a `const char *` of the `std::string`.  Make use of that!

Answer (score 1):

You could use c_str() method:

```
std::string somePath( "/lib/" );
remove( somePath.c_str() );
```